# Angular 2 with Materialize

Tags: node.js, angular, materialize

I am trying to run Materialize on my Angular 2 project but I think I am having trouble with the sorting of JS files in the index.html file.

I am using npm to install the node modules for Angular 2. I used the following commands to import the files needed for Angular 2 and materializecss

```
npm install
npm install materialize-css
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
     <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Project</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <link href="app/app.component.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Configure SystemJS -->
    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <pm-app>Loading App...</pm-app>
</body>

</html>
```

**Main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import "materialize-css";
import "angular2-materialize";
```

For app.component.css I am using the MaterializeCSS min.css content

I am using Visual Studio Code to compile this project.

**Note**
I am trying to convert this project from bootstrap to materialize. If need be, I can start a new project and just import all of the code needed. I'm not afraid of hard work :)

Thanks!

Edit: Here are the errors that the console is showing when I try to use npm start:
[image: Errors]

Comment: CLI or system js??

Comment: I would probably check out using angular-cli. It has a lot of community support. Then take a look at the npm package for materialize - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize

Comment: @Aravind I'm kinda new at this, what indications would it have if it were CLI or SystemJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the script reference in the systemjs

```
   "angular2-materialize": {
      "main": "npm:materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
    }
```

Update :
Add the following to package.json

```
//packages section

 "materialize-css": {
            "main": "dist/js/materialize"
        }


//mappings section

 "materialize-css": "node_modules/materialize-css",
 "angular2-materialize": "node_modules/angular2-materialize"
```

Comment: Are you talking about the systemjs.config.js? Sorry, I am new to this!

Comment: you are using System.js. if you are using CLI you will have webpack.config file instead of system.js

Comment: With that said, do you know what could be wrong? I added an image that shows the current console errors that I am receiving

Comment: check your typo there is a $ sign somewhere

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with my Main.ts? Is it not recognizing where to find "materialize-css" and "angular2-materialize"?

Comment: get rid of the line <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script> too. You'll probably need to show your systemjs.config.js file in the question.

Comment: Aravind has solved the issue for me. There were several issues, but we repackaged the node modules and changed many of the settings in the Systemjs.config.js file.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize. I think it's easier, there should be a @typings solution, if you look hard enough.